# Use of unassigned local variable in DLL in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I have refactored one DLL, I did almost same as existed by replacing new functions and models, my problem is with local variable which is not defined in existed one, but asking me to define it before use.

Existed code as like this:

```
    func<Employee<IdType>,bool> predicate;
    if(employees.Any<Employee<IdType>>(predicate))
    {
    }
```

Here I am getting error "Use of unassigned local variable 'predicate'" at if condition, but when I did declared predicate to null in first line, no build errors, but when I hit this condition, I am getting predicate value to be null and the next conditions are not executing. I am wondering why it is not happening in the existed DLL file.

Is there anyway I can fix this?

Comment: There is no way to answer this question since we don't have any references to the original DLL

Answer (score 1):

The delegate `predicate` has no value and yet you are trying to call it.  If you initialize it to point to a function or have an inline body, it will work:

```
Func<Employee<IdType>,bool> predicate = delegate(Employee<IdType> employee) {
    //you should return true if you want to count this employee, false otherwise
    return true;
};

if(employees.Any<Employee<IdType>>(predicate))
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable has to point to an existing predicate function otherwise Any cannot use it to filter.

A predicate has to return a true or a false.